# Ionic 3 is slow on ios 12

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am implementing an app using ionic 3. The app works perfectly on android and obn browser. However, when i build on iphone the performance is very slow and too lagging. For example i have a list item with infinite scroll that perform very badly only on ios.

I tried to use wkwebview and the app performs so much better. However, all my api requests fails(I use httpClient).

Is there any other solution to enhance the performance of the app?

Comment: Please include a code snippet of the infinite scroll.

Comment: it is not only about the infinite scroll. even the navigation is slow and buttons events are not fast.

Comment: If you are an angular developer, just try `nativescript`.

Comment: is it easy to switch to nativescript knowing that my app is almost finished

Comment: Did you try to build in release mode? ionic build ios --release --aot l in my case, this solved

Comment: For your API requests with wkwebview, do you have control over your API?  It should be pretty easy to get past the CORS issue with wkwebview if you control the API.